# javascript:window.print() not showing barcode for printing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making Mean Stack App in which I need to print `barcode`, I am using an angular js directive for generating code `128 barcode`, and it is generating well, but when I click print button `(javascript:window.print())` it is not showing the barcode in printing window neither in PDF, 
Here is my directive,

```
.directive('barcodeGenerator', [function() {
var Barcode = (function () {
    var barcode = {
        settings: {
            barWidth:   1,
            barHeight:    50,
            moduleSize:   5,
            showHRI:    false,
            addQuietZone: true,
            marginHRI:    5,
            bgColor:    "#FFFFFF",
            color:      "#000000",
            fontSize:   10,
            posX:     0,
            posY:     0
        },
        intval: function(val) {
            var type  = typeof(val);
            if ( type == 'string' ) {
                val = val.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, "");
                val = parseInt(val * 1, 10);
                return isNaN(val) || !isFinite(val)? 0: val;
            }
            return type == 'number' && isFinite(val)? Math.floor(val): 0;
        },
        code128: {
            encoding:[
                "11011001100", "11001101100", "11001100110", "10010011000",
                "10010001100", "10001001100", "10011001000", "10011000100",
                "10001100100", "11001001000", "11001000100", "11000100100",
                "10110011100", "10011011100", "10011001110", "10111001100",
                "10011101100", "10011100110", "11001110010", "11001011100",
                "11001001110", "11011100100", "11001110100", "11101101110",
                "11101001100", "11100101100", "11100100110", "11101100100",
                "11100110100", "11100110010", "11011011000", "11011000110",
                "11000110110", "10100011000", "10001011000", "10001000110",
                "10110001000", "10001101000", "10001100010", "11010001000",
                "11000101000", "11000100010", "10110111000", "10110001110",
                "10001101110", "10111011000", "10111000110", "10001110110",
                "11101110110", "11010001110", "11000101110", "11011101000",
                "11011100010", "11011101110", "11101011000", "11101000110",
                "11100010110", "11101101000", "11101100010", "11100011010",
                "11101111010", "11001000010", "11110001010", "10100110000",
                "10100001100", "10010110000", "10010000110", "10000101100",
                "10000100110", "10110010000", "10110000100", "10011010000",
                "10011000010", "10000110100", "10000110010", "11000010010",
                "11001010000", "11110111010", "11000010100", "10001111010",
                "10100111100", "10010111100", "10010011110", "10111100100",
                "10011110100", "10011110010", "11110100100", "11110010100",
                "11110010010", "11011011110", "11011110110", "11110110110",
                "10101111000", "10100011110", "10001011110", "10111101000",
                "10111100010", "11110101000", "11110100010", "10111011110",
                "10111101110", "11101011110", "11110101110", "11010000100",
                "11010010000", "11010011100", "11000111010"
            ],
            getDigit: function(code) {
                var tableB  = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
                var result  = "";
                var sum   = 0;
                var isum  = 0;
                var i   = 0;
                var j   = 0;
                var value = 0;

                // check each characters
                for(i=0; i<code.length; i++){
                    if (tableB.indexOf(code.charAt(i)) == -1){
                        return("");
                    }
                }

                // check firsts characters : start with C table only if enought numeric
                var tableCActivated = code.length > 1;
                var c = '';

                for (i=0; i<3 && i<code.length; i++) {
                    c = code.charAt(i);
                    tableCActivated &= c >= '0' && c <= '9';
                }

                sum = tableCActivated ? 105 : 104;

                // start : [105] : C table or [104] : B table
                result = this.encoding[ sum ];

                i = 0;
                while ( i < code.length ) {
                    if ( !tableCActivated) {
                        j = 0;
                        // check next character to activate C table if interresting
                        while ( (i + j < code.length) && (code.charAt(i+j) >= '0') && (code.charAt(i+j) <= '9') ) {
                            j++;
                        }

                        // 6 min everywhere or 4 mini at the end
                        tableCActivated = (j > 5) || ((i + j - 1 == code.length) && (j > 3));

                        if ( tableCActivated ){
                            result += this.encoding[ 99 ]; // C table
                            sum += ++isum * 99;
                        } //     2 min for table C so need table B
                    } else if ( (i == code.length) || (code.charAt(i) < '0') || (code.charAt(i) > '9') || (code.charAt(i+1) < '0') || (code.charAt(i+1) > '9') ) {
                        tableCActivated = false;
                        result += this.encoding[ 100 ]; // B table
                        sum += ++isum * 100;
                    }

                    if ( tableCActivated ) {
                        value = barcode.intval(code.charAt(i) + code.charAt(i+1)); // Add two characters (numeric)
                        i += 2;
                    } else {
                        value = tableB.indexOf( code.charAt(i) ); // Add one character
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    result  += this.encoding[ value ];
                    sum += ++isum * value;
                }

                result += this.encoding[sum % 103];// Add CRC
                result += this.encoding[106];// Stop
                result += "11";// Termination bar

                return(result);
            }
        },
        bitStringTo2DArray: function( digit) {//convert a bit string to an array of array of bit char
            var d = [];
            d[0] = [];

            for ( var i=0; i<digit.length; i++) {
                d[0][i] = digit.charAt(i);
            }

            return(d);
        },
        digitToCssRenderer: function( $container, settings, digit, hri, mw, mh, type) {// css barcode renderer
            var lines = digit.length;
            var columns = digit[0].length;
            var content = "";
            var len, current;
            var bar0 = "<div class='w w%s' ></div>";
            var bar1 = "<div class='b b%s' ></div>";

            for ( var y=0, x; y<lines; y++) {
                len = 0;
                current = digit[y][0];

                for ( x=0; x<columns; x++){
                    if ( current == digit[y][x] ) {
                        len++;
                    } else {
                        content += (current == '0'? bar0: bar1).replace("%s", len * mw);
                        current = digit[y][x];
                        len=1;
                    }
                }
                if ( len > 0) {
                    content += (current == '0'? bar0: bar1).replace("%s", len * mw);
                }
            }

            if ( settings.showHRI) {
                content += "<div style=\"clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: " + settings.bgColor + "; color: " + settings.color + "; text-align: center; font-size: " + settings.fontSize + "px; margin-top: " + settings.marginHRI + "px;\">"+hri+"</div>";
            }

            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = content;
            div.className = 'barcode '+ type +' clearfix-child';
            return div;
        },
        digitToCss: function($container, settings, digit, hri, type) {// css 1D barcode renderer
            var w = barcode.intval(settings.barWidth);
            var h = barcode.intval(settings.barHeight);

            return this.digitToCssRenderer($container, settings, this.bitStringTo2DArray(digit), hri, w, h, type);
        }
    };

    var generate  = function(datas, type, settings) {
        var
            digit = "",
            hri   = "",
            code  = "",
            crc   = true,
            rect  = false,
            b2d   = false
            ;

        if ( typeof(datas) == "string") {
            code = datas;
        } else if (typeof(datas) == "object") {
            code  = typeof(datas.code) == "string" ? datas.code : "";
            crc   = typeof(datas.crc) != "undefined" ? datas.crc : true;
            rect  = typeof(datas.rect) != "undefined" ? datas.rect : false;
        }

        if (code == "") {
            return(false);
        }

        if (typeof(settings) == "undefined") {
            settings = [];
        }

        for( var name in barcode.settings) {
            if ( settings[name] == undefined) {
                settings[name] = barcode.settings[name];
            }
        }

        switch (type) {
            case "std25":
            case "int25": {
                digit = barcode.i25.getDigit(code, crc, type);
                hri = barcode.i25.compute(code, crc, type);
                break;
            }
            case "ean8":
            case "ean13": {
                digit = barcode.ean.getDigit(code, type);
                hri = barcode.ean.compute(code, type);
                break;
            }
            case "upc": {
                digit = barcode.upc.getDigit(code);
                hri = barcode.upc.compute(code);
                break;
            }
            case "code11": {
                digit = barcode.code11.getDigit(code);
                hri = code;
                break;
            }
            case "code39": {
                digit = barcode.code39.getDigit(code);
                hri = code;
                break;
            }
            case "code93": {
                digit = barcode.code93.getDigit(code, crc);
                hri = code;
                break;
            }
            case "code128": {
                digit = barcode.code128.getDigit(code);
                hri = code;
                break;
            }
            case "codabar": {
                digit = barcode.codabar.getDigit(code);
                hri = code;
                break;
            }
            case "msi": {
                digit = barcode.msi.getDigit(code, crc);
                hri = barcode.msi.compute(code, crc);
                break;
            }
            case "datamatrix": {
                digit = barcode.datamatrix.getDigit(code, rect);
                hri = code;
                b2d = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( digit.length == 0) {
            return this;
        }

        if ( !b2d && settings.addQuietZone) {
            digit = "0000000000" + digit + "0000000000";
        }

        var fname = 'digitToCss' + (b2d ? '2D' : '');

        return barcode[fname](this, settings, digit, hri, type);
    };

    return generate;
}());

return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('barcodeGenerator', function(value){
            var code = Barcode(value, "code128",{barWidth:2}),
                code_wrapper = angular.element("<div class='barcode code128'></div>")

            code_wrapper.append(code);
            angular.element(element).html('').append(code_wrapper);

        });
    }
}
```

And here is barcode generating code,

```
  <div ng-model='myInput' barcode-generator="{{myInput}}" style="height:208px;">
                </div>
```

Here are the screenshots
[It shows barcode on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYTN2.jpg)

[But not shows up while printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6MxP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's because some browsers has turned off rendering background-color in print mode by default. You won't force all users to mess up with browser settings, but you can replace background-color with border-width like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.barcode.code128 > div.b {
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-color: #000000 !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b1 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b2 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 2px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b3 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 3px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b4 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 4px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b5 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 5px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b6 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 6px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b7 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 7px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b8 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 8px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b9 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 9px !important;
}
.barcode.code128 .b10 {
    width: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 10px !important;
}
```